# not able to persist username using twitter omni-auth in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, omniauth

I am trying to implement omniauth twitter to authenticate user using twitter in my application. When I try to "login with twitter", It takes me to "Authorize App" twitter page. When I click "Authorize App" button, It tries to redirect me to my app and shows me as as already logged user in twitter.( as I am already logged in twitter in another tab of my browser). But then I display me registration page without persisting username. I am following Ryan `http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised` devise with omniauth. How to persist username when log in with twitter. Please suggest me.

I have attached my application code on below link.

[app code](https://gist.github.com/Vinay50/5518614)

Please let me know if  you need more code to be pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Devise is looking for an email. Can't be persisted without.

You can :
- change the email field null=>true using a migration
- generate a dummy email when provider is twitter